# Cannot telnet to a local server

Tags: networking, port

I want to reach a Windows PC on my LAN on a specific port, but it fails and I can't find the reason. Can you spot anything?

- PC is running Windows 10. I have disabled the Windows Firewall on it (for now), and there is no other firewall software installed.
- I can ping its IP from another LAN PC, so I know it's reachable. All my devices have fixed IP addresses.
- The machine is running a server that is listening on port 19132.
- From another computer with no outbound firewall rules, `telnet 192.168.1.30 19132` returns `Could not open connection to the host, on port 19132: Connect failed`, and PuTTY says `connection refused`.

[image: network error: connection refused]

What am I missing?

---

**Update** based on comments:

- I'm almost certain that the Minecraft bedrock server uses only TCP and not UDP, thus `telnet` would be meaningful as test.
- The `Get-NetTCPConnection` suggestion from @HelpingHand returned no output at all, even in the admin console.

  - if it helps, the executable path is `C:\Users\torbe\games\minecraft\server\bedrock\bedrock-server-1.17.40.06\bedrock_server.exe`

[image: output of Get-NetTCPConnection]

Comment: Maybe run the following PS one liner on on the machine running the "server": `Get-NetTCPConnection | Select-Object -Property *,@{'Name' = 'ProcessName';'Expression'={(Get-Process -Id $_.OwningProcess).Name}} | where localport -eq 19132 | select ProcessName, owningprocess, State, localaddress, localport, remoteaddress, remoteport`  What does it return?

Answer (score 1):

The bedrock edition of the Minecraft [server uses UDP rather than TCP](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Bedrock_Dedicated_Server#Configuration) like the Java version.

This means that `telnet` cannot test the port. [Microsoft PortQry Command Line Port Scanner](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/portqry-exe-command-line-utility) and [optional GUI](https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/f/4/3f4c6a54-65f0-4164-bdec-a3411ba24d3a/portqryui.exe) can test UDP ports and confirms that the port is in fact open:

```
PS C:\Users\xyzzy\Downloads> .\PortQry.exe -n 192.168.1.30 -p BOTH -o 19132
Querying target system called:
 192.168.1.30
Attempting to resolve IP address to a name...
IP address resolved to DESKTOP-PC.LOCAL
querying...
TCP port 19132 (unknown service): NOT LISTENING
UDP port 19132 (unknown service): LISTENING or FILTERED
PS C:\Users\xyzzy\Downloads>
```

Because my network is already configured, it is even [accessible from the WAN](https://check-host.net/check-udp?host=golfbravo.eu:19132) side.